# Map reduce with mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get a map reduce operation to work using Nodejs, mongoose and MongoDB.
I've got a fairly flat schema structure and I want to get a list of value/date pairs per 'named' object. There is clearly something wrong with the map reduce function but I can't see how to fix it to get the format I'm after.

The MongoDB document schema is as follows:

```
{ "name" : "object1", "value" : "123", "date" : "2013-01-02 01:00:00" }
{ "name" : "object1", "value" : "456", "date" : "2013-01-02 02:00:00" }
{ "name" : "object2", "value" : "123", "date" : "2013-01-02 02:00:00" }
```

The map reduce functions I'm using in my Mongoose Schema are as follows:

```
var o = {};
o.map = function () { 
  emit(
    { 'name': this.name },
    {'data': [ { 'value': this.value, 'date': this.date} ] }
  )
}

o.reduce = function (k, vals) { 
  var reduced = {'data': []};
  for (var i in vals) {
    reduced.data.push(vals[i]);
  }
  return reduced;
}

this.mapReduce(o, function(err, model) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  model.find().exec(cb);
});
```

What I'd like to see is some JSON along the lines of

```
[
  {
    "name": "object1",
    "data": [
      {
        "value": "123",
        "date": "2013-01-02T01:00:00.123456"
      },
      {
        "value": "456",
        "date": "2013-01-02T02:00:00.123456"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "object2",
    "data": [
      {
        "value": "123",
        "date": "2013-04-22T13:10:03.893018"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
```

But I end up getting this nested mess! Can someone give me a pointer on what I've missed!!

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "name": "object1"
    },
    "value": {
      "data": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "value": "123",
                      "date": "2013-01-02T02:00:00.123456"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "value": "465",
                      "date": "2013-01-02T01:00:00.123456"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that: (not tested but the idea is here I think :))

```
var o = {};
o.map = function () { 
  emit(this.name, { 'value': this.value, 'date': this.date} )
}

o.reduce = function (k, vals) { 
  var reduced = {name: k, data : []};
  for (var i in vals) {
    reduced.data.push(vals[i]);
  }
  return reduced;

  // or just return vals? it's already the array you want.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that sorta gets me there but I end up with the same issue with the horrible nested data arrays as above :(

Comment: _id for the key is normal. did you tried to just return vals?